# Linear layout inside TabHost only showing one element

Tags: android, tabview, android-linearlayout

I have this layout file in my android application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="this is a tab" />
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="this is another tab" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutSearch"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview4"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                    android:text="Search here" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editSearch"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

My problem is that `LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layoutSearch"` shows only one of the elements it contains (the text view, in the code above) If I remove the textview, it shows the EditText.

How do I make it display both (and more) elements?

Comment: I know it might look like I'm copying an iPhone app, but IMO this makes it easier to see the rest of the screen, when they're on top your hand covers the entire screen..

Comment: You're right, maybe I should move it up, I'll think about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of excess layout there, but it looks like the real issue is that `layoutSearch` is a vertical LinearLayout with two children, but the first child's height is set to `fill_parent`, so you naturally never see the second one. Try setting its height to `0px` but giving it a `layout_weight` of `1`, and it should expand to take all the available space not taken by the `EditText` below it.

Comment: I changed the height to `wrap_content` and it's working now. One more question though: you said that there's a lot of excess layout.. how do you recommend I do this in a better way? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh I just meant relative to your question, all the container stuff around `layoutSearch` wasn't relevant. You could probably flatten things a bit with a RelativeLayout if you wanted to, though.

Comment: Ah right, I didn't know which part was causing the problem, that's why I posted everything. Anyway, thanks again for your help!